# Como se la integracion de 2 htaccess con ptpasswd?

Tags: php, linux, apache

realice una pregunta y muy amable Alvaro ha contestado, solo que yo no entiendo de códigos y no se como se hace integrar  con  path's 
la pregunta y respuesta era esta:

> ¿si tengo 2 archivos htaccess en diferentes directorios -Necesito crear 2 htpasswd o 1 htpasswd sirve para los dos ?

Un único htpasswd valdría para los dos. Lo único es que puede que tengas que definir path's diferentes en cada fichero htaccess. Pero los dos podrán usarlo sin problemas (ejemplo: podría darse el caso de que tengas diferentes áreas protegidas dentro de tu sitio web pero los usuarios/contraseñas sean comunes en ambas).

agradeceré información paso a paso, gracias. (es para hacer mi pagina segura)

Answer (score 1):

La idea es tienes que definir la ruta al mismo fichero `.htpasswd` en los dos ficheros `.htaccess` y eso es lo único que tendría que cambiar de uno a otro (y ni siquiera eso si usas rutas absolutas en lugar de relativas).

Por ejemplo, imagina que tienes este sistema de ficheros:

```
/
|-- Passwords
|   `-- .htpasswd
`-- MiServidor
    `- www
        |-- Carpeta1
        |   `-- Subcarpeta1
        |      `-- .htaccess
        `-- Carpeta2
            `-- .htaccess
```

Donde tienes dos fichero `.htaccess` en diferentes carpetas dentro de tu servidor web, y un fichero único `.htpasswd` fuera del directorio root de tu servidor web.

Entonces, el `.htaccess` que hay en Subcarpeta1 tendría este contenido:

```
Authtype Basic
AuthName "Escribe lo que quieras aquí"
AuthUserFile ../../../../Passwords/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Y el `.htaccess` que hay en Carpeta2 tendría el contenido:

```
Authtype Basic
AuthName "Escribe lo que quieras aquí"
AuthUserFile ../../../Passwords/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Si te fijas, los dos tienen el mismo contenido, lo único que cambia es la ruta (*path*) al fichero `.htpasswd` porque están a diferentes niveles. Pero ambos podrían tener el mismo contenido si la ruta fuera absoluta desde la raíz del árbol de ficheros (`/Passwords/.htaccess` o `c:\Passwords\.htaccess` en UNIX/Linux y Windows respectivamente).

Comment: Muchas gracias Alvaro M. ! aunque como soy novata en todo esto, Me resulta un poco dificil. entender . ahora me queda por preguntar como sabria la ruta para cada archivo.? .Gracias.

Comment: @LitaSan La ruta a poner dependerá de dónde estén los ficheros. Podrías usar una ruta absoluta y así sería igual en ambos `.htaccess`

Comment: Gracias por tu amabilidad!   como dije antes no se nada de este  mundo de codigos, solamente me he puesto a tono solo por tener mi proxima pagina web un poco mas segura con el archivo htaccess.